# Differentiate style for a grid depending on axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to give a different to my grid along the x axis and the y axis.

Though when I call ax.grid it seems to hide the grid instead of configuring it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x = numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
y = numpy.power(x, 2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
ax.set_yticks(numpy.arange(0, 1., 0.1))
ax.grid(axis='x', linestyle="-", linewidth=1)  # doesn't work
ax.grid(axis='y', linestyle="--", linewidth=1)  # doesn't work
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Current state]

Without the ax.grid calls, the grid appears but the style is not what I want.

[image: Without ax.grid calls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `plt.grid` works for me:

```
x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
y = np.power(x, 2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1., 0.1))
ax.grid(axis='x', linestyle="-", linewidth=1)  # doesn't work
ax.grid(axis='y', linestyle="--", linewidth=1)  # doesn't work
ax.scatter(x, y)

# plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You rock!

I misunderstood that plt.grid was overriding the rest.